# Social.localUser.Authenticate returns false everytime in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console

I am using the latest version of GooglePlayGames plugin ( 0.9.50). I have added the  Android resouces from play console. I have also verified that my SHA-1 fingerprint is correct. The SHA-1 fingerprint of upload certificate in Google play console and the OAuth 2.0 client ID in Google developer console are same. Still Social.localUser.Authenticate returns false everytime. I have also tried publishing my game in alpha after adding the tester's accounts. Still Social.localUser.Authenticate returned false. When I open the game from my phone, not even that Google Play Games Sign-in "green thing" is showing. I don't have any errors or warnings. The following is my code:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames;

public class Playgames : MonoBehaviour {

public bool IsConnectedToGoogleServices { set; get; }

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    #if (UNITY_ANDROID || (UNITY_IPHONE && !NO_GPGS))
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    #endif

    SignIn();
}

public bool SignIn()
{
    if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices) {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
            Debug.Log("Sign-in " + success.ToString() );
        });
    }
    return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
}
}
```

Could someone please help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks exactly the same as mine (regarding the login part). So it does not seem to be a code issue. 
My best advice is to retrace your steps in google play console. 
Note: I did use an alpha track for testing.

Comment: I have triple checked everything. Couldn't find the issue :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Play Signing then the signing key in the app downloaded from Google Play will not be the same as the upload certificate. Have you added the signing key from Google Play Signing to the Google Play Games API configuration? This is described in the [release checklist](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) step 4 "Register your app signing key with API providers".

> If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.
>
> To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:
>
> - Sign in to your Play Console.
>
>   - Select an app.
>   - On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
>   - From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires.

Comment: What did you mean by "Have you added the signing key from Google Play Signing to the Google Play Games API configuration?". Are you talking about adding SHA-1 fingerprint of upload certificate from Google play console to the OAuth 2.0 client ID in Google developer console? If yes. I have already done that.

Comment: The point is it isn't the SHA1 of the upload certificate you need to add. It is the SHA1 of the Google signing key. Read the part above more carefully: "register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with "

Comment: That is when you upload the apk in production and then publish. My app is not in production. It is in alpha. I have tested locally too. Anyway I have tried both SHA1s , but didnt seem to work.

Comment: The same holds true for alpha. It is still signed by Google.

Comment: My leaderboard worked when I removed admob. There is some conflict between admob and google play games plugin. I am getting the following error when I try to build:                                                CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools"

-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool SignIn()
{
    if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices) {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
            Debug.Log("Sign-in " + success.ToString() );
        });
    }
    return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
}
```

The supplied callback for the Authenticate method is **not** instantaneous - the callback is `bool success => {...}` lambda expression. Thus, you cannot guarantee the callback is executed before returning `IsConnectedToGoogleServices` to the caller, which by default is set to `false`. Perhaps, that could be your issue?